# Understanding CPU Utilization in Perfmon

Tags: performance-monitor

I'm running some tests on my machine with Intel i5 quad core processor. I see that the %Processor time _Total looks like average of all the other processor cores. Is it a sum of all the processor cores or average? Please let me know how to interpret it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The description in Perfmon for the %Processor Time counter (when checking "Show description"), is the following:

"... This counter is the primary indicator of processor activity, and displays the *average percentage* of busy time observed during the sample interval. ..."

I have not yet found any online reference as to how the _Total counter is calculated, but by observing the _Total counter in Perfmon, you can see its value is the average of the individual instances (0, 1, 2, 3, ...).

For example, after pausing Perfmon on the PC I'm typing this on (a dual core i5 with 4 threads), the individual CPU percentage values are:

- (0) 3.126
- (1) 3.126
- (2) 1.564
- (3) 6.251
- _Total: 3.517

As (3.126 + 3.126 + 1.564 + 6.251) / 4 = 3.517, you can see that _Total is indeed the average of the four individual instances.